# Can't find the reason why I have syntax error, unexpected end of file

Tags: php

I have spent a lot of time to find what's wrong with my code, but I couldn't find the reason why I have this error. In the logs, I have an error about the last line. The error is:

> "PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in .... on line 57"

Here is the code :

```
<?php
if (!ISSET($_SESSION['id_user_admin'])) {
    header('location: ' . BASE_ADMIN_URL);
} else {
?>

<?php
    $this->title = WEBSITE_NAME . ' |  Panneau d\'Administration';
?>
<?php
    require('extendedcards_menu.php');
?>
<?php
    require __DIR__ . '/../errors/confirmation.php';
?>
<?php
    $htmlRows = '';
    if ($number_of_items) {

        while ($item = $items->fetch()) {
            $htmlRows .= '
        <tr>
      <td><h6 class="mt-2 text-left">' . $this->clean($item['date_creation_fr']) . '</h6></td>
      <td><h6 class="mt-2 text-left"><a target="_blank" href="' . BASE_ADMIN_URL . 'users/userread/' . $this->clean($item['id_user']) . '">
      ' . $this->clean($item['firstname']) . '&nbsp;' . $this->clean($item['name']) . '</a></span></td>
      <td><a href="' . BASE_ADMIN_URL . 'extendedcardsadmin/extendedcardread/' . $this->clean($item['itemid']) . '">
      <img width="125px" src="' . BASE_URL . 'public/images/extendedcard_images/' . $this->clean($item['image']) . '" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded-right"
      alt="' . $this->clean($item['title']) . '" title="' . $this->clean($item['title']) . '"></a></td>
      <td><span class="text-body newstitle"><a href="' . BASE_ADMIN_URL . 'extendedcardsadmin/extendedcardread/' . $this->clean($item['itemid']) . '">
      <h6 class="mt-2 text-left">' . $this->clean($item['title']) . '</h6></a></span></td>
      <td>';
?><?php
            if ($this->clean($item['draft']) == "yes") {
?><span class="badge badge-warning">Br.</span><?
            }
            ;
            '</td>
      <td><a href="' . BASE_ADMIN_URL . 'extendedcardsadmin/extendedcardread/' . $this->clean($item['itemid']) . '" role="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Modifier</a></td>
      <td><a href="' . BASE_ADMIN_URL . 'extendedcardsadmin/moveitemtobin/' . $this->clean($item['itemid']) . '" role="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Supprimer</a></td>
      </tr>
  ';
        }
        $htmlPagination .= '
      <tr>';
        if ($items_current_page > $number_of_items_pages) {
            require __DIR__ . '/../errors/item_not_found.php';
        } else {
            require('extendedcards_pagination.php');
        }
        '
    </tr>';
    } else {
        $htmlRows .= '
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" align="center">Aucune Extended Card trouvée.</td>
        </tr>';
        $htmlPagination .= ' ';
    }
    $data = array(
        "html" => $htmlRows,
        "html" => $htmlPagination
    );
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
<?php
}
;
?>
```

Can you help me to find what's wrong?

Comment: OhLord! ;) `$htmlPagination .= '
    <tr>'` is missing a closing `;`. `require('extendedcards_pagination.php')}.'
    </tr>'.;` Is faulty. `</tr>'.;` is missing a part

Comment: Proper code indentation and formatting, maybe extracting some parts into functions will make that code more readable _and_ more maintainable. Maybe using a proper IDE that can highlight such errors wouldn't be bad either

Comment: Thanks @brombeer I've edited the code, but I still have the same error :(

Comment: `'</td>` is missing a variable, should most likely be `$htmlRows .= '</td>...`. `}
            ;` No `;` after loops

Comment: Also, not sure if your PHP is set up to use short tags, you might want to replace `<?` with `<?php`

Comment: `'
    </tr>';` is just standing there, also missing a variable

Comment: Also, there's no need to constantly open/close Php like in the first part of your code. Use `<?php`, write _all_ your PHP code, close it with `?>`

Comment: Thanks ! I corrected my code, I don't have this error anymore.